# how to import document into collection in mongo db csv file

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have CSV file need to upload into mongo db collection, how can i upload into collection name suppose cleanup in db. how can i import using mongoimport.

```
_id     ban     attuid  trblFndCode     causeCode   jobId   wrid    wrStatus    dispatchStartTime   dispatchEndTime         narrativeText   dispatchTimeZone    returnReasonCode    returnReasonDesc    dbName  ijackPlacedInd  ijackOverReasonCode     ijackOverReason     areaOfIntrest   areaName    extKey  extKey2     plantEquipType  dwaActivity     activityCount   activitySpans   recordPublishIndicator  recordPublishDateTime 
    284216618   je449y  252 656 W0203022782 99122249    DISPATCH    2020-07-23T02:26:00Z    2020-07-23T04:01:00Z     je449y; cx wantedTo relocate rg due to not getting speeds purchased upgraded cx to 50x10 looked for phone jacks but none available to relocate rg separated 2.4 and 5ghz and changed channel cx getting speeds purchased    PACIFIC            zlp24827.vci.att.com:1524:p1c3d842                      L47988266   W0203022782 ATLAS-IEFS              N   
    306767694   jp109y          W0200012441 99072831    DISPATCH    2020-07-23T01:42:00Z    2020-07-23T04:03:00Z     jp109y; pair changes... CIM assist. Cat5 homerun Internet registered and active BBTgnpCXvp.     PACIFIC            zlp24827.vci.att.com:1524:p1c3d842                      5823735537  W0200012441 ATLAS-IEFS              N   
    135845316   av1734  420 302 W0202029664 99098470    DISPATCH    2020-07-22T15:16:00Z    2020-07-23T04:12:00Z     av1734; repaired underground and new modem added    PACIFIC            zlp24827.vci.att.com:1524:p1c3d842                      L47850729   W0202029664 ATLAS-IEFS              N   
    306833837   jg104x          W0203027621 99125008    DISPATCH    2020-07-23T01:21:00Z    2020-07-23T04:18:00Z     jg104x; installed RG in LVGR HSIA 3 devices customized SSID and password bbt pass.      PACIFIC            zlp24827.vci.att.com:1524:p1c3d842                      5804912395  W0203027621 ATLAS-IEFS              N   
    151563504   jl6484          W0202020573 99093024    DISPATCH    2020-07-23T00:40:00Z    2020-07-23T04:30:00Z     jl6484; removed bt in 2 locations access issues to terminal. True test failed due to bt on f1. Cst needs IW run. Sync good to sni.      PACIFIC            zlp24827.vci.att.com:1524:p1c3d842                      5801222767  W0202020573 ATLAS-IEFS              N
```

Have tried with below command, but  getting below error, kindly suggest:

```
[motive@al15423 sil]$  /home/motive/fon/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-4.0.5/bin/mongoimport  --host nonprod-sfldmibb-al15423-001-ingress.idns.cci.att.com:32414  -u 'hub' -p 'ccess' --authenticationDatabase admin --db agentaction --collection hubdwarecordscleanups --type csv --headerline --file /tmp/DWA_Records_23-July_2020.csv
2020-08-04T10:32:23.645-0400    connected to: nonprod-sfldmibb-zlt16161-001-ingress.idns.cci.att.com:32414
2020-08-04T10:32:24.499-0400    error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: agentaction.hubdwarecordscleanups index: _id_ dup key: { : "" }
2020-08-04T10:32:25.115-0400    error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: agentaction.hubdwarecordscleanups index: _id_ dup key: { : "" }
2020-08-04T10:32:25.528-0400    error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: agentaction.hubdwarecordscleanups index: _id_ dup key: { : "" }
2020-08-04T10:32:25.876-0400    error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: agentaction.hubdwarecordscleanups index: _id_ dup key: { : "" }
2020-08-04T10:32:26.193-0400    error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: agentaction.hubdwarecordscleanups index: _
```

Comment: HI Prasad can you check and confirm.

Comment: What's your error?